# Is it possible to limit connections per "user agent" in htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Say my goal is to limit the number of users visiting my site concurrently via "Mozilla" (firefox) user agent, is it possible to do in apache 2.2?

I'm thinking using something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mozilla" [NC]
```

and

```
MaxClients            0
```

However I don't know (if possible) how to make both rules work together?

Answer (score 1):

No. Think of MaxClients as a server side high level variable, and Rewrites to be something at the vhost. They don't mix in the way you're wanting them to.

You'll need to look for a 3rd party module that can do what you're looking for - Something like http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/ might fit your needs?

This may not solve whatever issue you're trying to solve, however. For example, Mozilla could be sent by a lot of different applications that aren't specifically Firefox. Here's some examples of a few mobile devices.

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"

"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; de-de; Vodafone Smart Tab 4 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.2 Mobile Safari/534.30"

Are they using Chrome, Safari, some apple browser or Firefox? I have no idea. You'd need to be more specific, if you're looking for specifically, only Firefox browsers (see http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/ for a list of those strings).